# How to load a dataset of pictures from Google Cloud Storage to a Jupyter VM Instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, jupyter

I am new to gcloud storage and VMs. My problem is I have a big dataset of images stored in a bucket in gcloud, I want to do two things:

1. first, I want to load this dataset to my Jupyter instance to run some deep learning models. But I didn't find any clear method to do so.
2. second, I want to save some output images to a different bucket and so some other files.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/) tool to mount a Cloud Storage bucket to your instance. The mounted bucket behaves similarly to a persistent disk even though Cloud Storage buckets are object storage. Once you have the buckets as disks you can make it so that the first bucket inputs the images into the deep learning model and the output be saved in the second bucket.